# Caching details from TCP dump

Tags: browser, tcp, browser-cache, wireshark, tcpdump

I browsed a lot of data (lets say visited 30 websites) and saved all the traffic in tcpdump using wireshark. I want to know the caching time(max age) for all the objects in all the websites. Is there any smart way to accurately get caching life for the objects?

Issue: In http response when you get the caching age it just tells you the file type, how we can relate to each response with the correct request.

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Apply a display filter:
http.request_in || http.response_in || http.cache_control

Add [columns](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDisplayPopUpSection.html#ChWorkPacketDetailsPanePopUpMenu).
Select in the Packet Details pane: http.request_in
Right-click and select Apply as Column
Repeat those steps for "http.response_in" and "http.cache_control".

Export the displayed packets to a .csv file to get an overview.
Go to File
Export Packet Dissections
as "CSV" (Comma Separated Values packet summary) file...
Packet Range:
select All packets
Select Displayed
Hope this helps.

*Edit (see comment): find `http.request_in`*
Apply a display filter:
http.request.method == "GET"
Select a packet
Go to the [Packet Details pane](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketDetailsPaneSection.html)
Right-click on Hypertext Trasnsfer Protocol
Select [Expand Subtrees](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseViewMenuSection.html)
Look for `[Response in frame:  ]`

FYI
[Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/)
[http](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/http.html)

Comment: Hi it did work Thanks. I want to know where is the http.request_in in the packet detail pane. Thanks again